# Como pegar o id do elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho este HTML que tem o id que é inserido no laço de repetição...

```
<div class="item-total elemento" id = ${id}>
```

Logo, tenho essa função:

```
$(document).on('touchstart', '.elemento', function (){

});
```

Neste '.elemento' na realidade, eu queria fazer algo tipo `'.elemento > id'` do elemento que cliquei, lembrando que essa função está fora do laço de repetição... tem alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: não entendi direito, cada um dos `div` deve executar uma função diferente?  por isso vc quer fazer um laço pelo ID?

Comment: @h3nr1ke na realidade não. Ele vai fazer a mesma coisa. Só que aí quando faço dessa maneira ele aplica para todos, e eu só quero que faça no elemento alvo.

Comment: Entendi, então basta usar o `$(this)` dentro da função, por exemplo, `$(this).addClass("active");`, com isso somente o item clicado sofrerá a mudança, demais itens não.

Comment: Não tem como fazer isso desta forma. O seletor `.elemento > id` significa selecionar um elemento pela classe `.elemento` e um filho direto com a tag `id`, só que não existe a tag `id`. O sinal `>` significa filho-direto.

Comment: @Sam Eu imaginei. Foi apenas para exemplificar. Mas achei que tivesse como fazer algo do tipo direto na função.

Answer (score 2):

Nos casos que você tem vários elementos com a mesma classe, mas quer pegar o ID do elemento que disparou o evento, deve utilizar `this` (JavaScript puro) ou `$(this)` (jQuery), no exemplo abaixo só mudei o evento de 'touchstart' para o 'click':

```js
$(document).on('click', '.elemento', function (){
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-total elemento" id ="1">1</div>
<div class="item-total elemento" id ="2">2</div>
```

Comment: Eu gostaria de aplicar na própria função, por exemplo:

$(document).on('click', '.elemento > id', function (){
  
});

tem como?

Comment: Você está querendo selecionar o id na função, não precisa disso porque já vai acessa-lo pelo `this`.

Comment: Como eu quero aplicar $(document).on('touchstart', '.elemento', function (){

});

no id do elemento essa seria a melhor forma? estou fazendo assim pois esses html foram inseridos através do append.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma alternativa poderia ser:

```
<div class="item-total elemento" id = ${id} onClick="funcao(this)">
```

Onde logo após, em seu arquivo JavaScript, a sua função deverá ser escrita

```
function funcao(elemento) {
   // TODO
}
```

Fornecendo o `this` como parâmetro te permite recuperar as propriedades do campo como: `this.value, this.id, etc`

Answer (score 0):

Para interagir com o elemento ativado pelo evento apenas vc pode

```
$(document).on('touchstart', '.elemento', function (){
    // adiciona uma class active apenas no elemento o selecionado
    $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

`$(this)` sempre fará referência ao elemento que causou o trigger do evento.